# Natural sort for sortby Name

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, sorting

I want to sort catalog products by name in natural order. In order to achieve it i created a custom module and overwrote Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar.

```
   public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $this->_collection = $collection;

        $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

        // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
        $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
        if ($limit) {
            $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
        }
        if ($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'name') {           
            //i'm assigning the custom sorted collection
            $this->_collection = $this->_naturalsort($this->_collection);
            //printing the collection to check whether it's in proper order
             $this->_test($this->_collection);
        }else if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
        }        
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _naturalsort($collection){
        $prodarr = $collection->exportToArray(); 
        usort($prodarr, function($a, $b) {          
            return strnatcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
        });
        $collectionsorted = new Varien_Data_Collection();
        foreach($prodarr as $item)
        {
            $varienObject = new Varien_Object();
            $varienObject->setData($item);
            $collectionsorted->addItem($varienObject);

        }         
        return $collectionsorted;
    }
    protected function _test($collection){
       foreach($collection as $item2)
        {
            Mage::log($item2['name']);
        }        
    }
```

When logging the collection using my _test method the products are in correct order. Still it doesn't affect the frontend view. The frontend displays a non sorted collection. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You replaced the collection *in the toolbar block*, but the *list block* which is used to display the products still contains the original collection.

Since the toolbar adds the sort order, changing the order there seems like the right choice. But you don't have access to the list block at that point, so another change will be necessary after the call to [`$toolbar->setCollection()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php#L159)

There is an event, `catalog_block_product_list_collection` but unfortunately the only parameter is the collection itself, so you can *modify* it, but not *replace* it.

My suggestion is to rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::_beforeToHtml()` like this:

```
protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
    parent::_beforeToHtml();
    if ($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'name')
    {
        $this->_collection = $this->_naturalsort($this->_collection);
    }
}
```

and move `_naturalsort()` there. The rewrite of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar::setCollection()` is not necessary anymore then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try this out and mark it as correct

Comment: I rewrote Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::_beforeToHtml() like above. But unfortunately $this->getCurrentOrder() is empty

Comment: Use `$this->getToolbar()->getCurrentOrder()` instead

Comment: I get Fatal error: Call to a member function getCurrentOrder() on a non-object

Comment: Ah, sorry, it's `$this->getChild('toolbar')->getCurrentOrder () `

Comment: Thanks that issue was solved but $this->_collection is empty and also i tried $this->getChild('toolbar')->_collection. Still it's empty

Comment: I tried this code but still the sort was not visible in the frontend

`$collection = $this->_naturalsort($this->_getProductCollection());

$this->getChild('toolbar')->setCollection($collection); `